# Why does this procedure fail without "mov edx, 0"?

Tags: assembly, x86

I was working on an assignment to take a user provided integer and determine if it is prime. The program I wrote worked fine I just don't exactly understand why I need to set edx to 0 every cycle.

```
    ;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
IsPrime PROC
;
; This determines if the integer is a prime
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mov ebx,eax                 ;Copying eax -> ebx
sar eax,1                   ;Arithmetic shift right to make eax = eax/2
mov esi,eax                 ;Setting esi = half of our number
mov ecx,1

    isPrimeLoop:
        add ecx, 1          ;increments ecx, starts at 2
        cmp ecx,esi
        ja itsPrime

        mov edx,0
        mov eax,ebx
        div ecx             ;dividing to see if it has a remainder or not
        cmp edx,0
        jz itsNotPrime
        jmp isPrimeLoop

    itsNotPrime:                ;displays results for numbers that are not prime
        mov eax,ebx
        call WriteDec
        mWrite " is not a prime number it is divisible by "
        mov eax,ecx
        call WriteDec
        call Crlf
        jmp endPrime



    itsPrime:                   ;displays results for numbers that are prime
        mov eax,ebx
        call WriteDec
        mWrite " is a prime number."
        call Crlf
        jmp endPrime

    endPrime:
ret
IsPrime ENDP
```

Answer (score 2):

Because div divides edx:eax by whatever. The result lands in eax and the remainder in edx. If the result doesn't fit in eax (likely if edx contains garbage), an interrupt is raised, which the OS translates into SIGFPE.

Comment: Right but if there is a remainder edx should be the remainder and if there is not a remainder it should be set to 0 because edx is the zero flag.

Comment: Uhh div has 64 bits of input.

Comment: Would there be a better way to avoid the issue in this procedure than having to pass 0 to edx every cycle?

Comment: No, in your code before `div ecx` (or before any `div reg32/mem32`) you need `mov edx,0` / `xor edx,edx` / `sub edx,edx` to clear `edx` after the previous `div`, because the dividend is always in `edx:eax` and `edx` is used to store the remainder. Anyway, if you're learning x86 assembly, it's not useful to worry about optimization, as nowadays x86 assembly optimization is **a lot** harder than trying to leave one instruction out. Also, you're confusing the terminology, `edx` is **not** zero flag (ZF). Zero flag is set according to the result of many instructions. After `div` ZF is undefined.

Comment: Setting a register to 0 is practically always done with `xor reg,reg`. So I would suggest to get used to doing this, instead of `mov reg, 0`. First, it makes it easier to read code from others, and second it's more efficient.

Comment: Devolus is correct. The only reason to use the mov form is the xor form clobbers flags, which may occasionally be an issue.